# Create SQLite DB in Android library

Tags: android, sqlite

I've seen a lot of ties between the onCreate and onOpen methods and SQLite database management in Android.

I am an iOS developer and I'm trying to "translate" (so to speak) my cocoa library so it could be used on Android. I need to create an SQLite database at runtime. I don't have an activity - since this is a library I'm creating. It seems I can't create a DB without an activity, is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create sqlite db, you don't basically need an activity in the library.it needs a **context**!!,
 You can have a method in library/class which basically take a context in input/parameter and create database.

This context can be passed from application activity or service or receiver.

Comment: So how can I cater for this? My needs are very simple, I have a Database class and the first thing I need is it open/create a database. Where can I get a context from? Knowing that I'm trying to create a library for others to use. It feels like I need to create an entire android app to get this working ?

Comment: no, You did not get my point, database will be created at the first call to constructor sqliteopenhelper, where you can get a context in the constructor parameter. 
yes the db will only be created , when an application calls ur library!!

Comment: Of course that's great. Will look into this sqliteopenhelper. I got the impression it was a third party helper class and I need to do everything from scratch

Comment: Yes you need to create a class which must extends SQLiteOpenHelper, then the constructor will need a context as argument, which basically need to creat database. TO open database for read/write you will need to call this.getWritableDatabase(); or readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you should not be able to open a database without an activity. You need to extend SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public class MyDatabase {
private final DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "com.my.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                //use db.execSQL to create the database
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
               // use db.execSQL to update (modify) the database
    }
}

public SQLiteDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return db;
}
```

}

Comment: as context you can pass your application context in case you want from the application that will use the library