# Creating SQLite DB at runtime without a context

Tags: java, android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create SQLite DB in Android library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333580/create-sqlite-db-in-android-library)

I am making a Java library and I need an SQLite database to be opened or created at runtime for my library to store data etc...

All the SQLite API for Android I've seen requires a context, from an activity to create a DB,since I'm doing a library, without activity etc... how can I get an SQLite DB ?

The problem is my library has only one public class, and inside my library in my inner workings I need to create a SQLite DB for private use. 
So I can't just ask the user to send in a context. Or can I ?

Just see for how does Google do it in their library ? 
At no point when I'm using the analytics library for Android do I pass anything other then an app id for analytics. And In their documentation you can read: "Pageviews, events and Ecommerce hits are stored in an ***SQLite database*** and dispatched to the Google Analytics servers periodically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I get an SQLite DB ?

Have the consumer of your library supply you with a `Context`.

> So I can't just ask the user to send in a context. Or can I ?

Yes, you can. If you notice, many classes in the `android.*` packages have methods that take a `Context` as a parameter. You, too, can have methods that take a `Context` as a parameter.

Now, you will need to document your intended use of the `Context` and the lifespan of the objects that will touch it, so consumers of your library can pass in an appropriate one. For example, if your library will be creating a static data member that holds onto a `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you will want to actually have the consumer of the library supply you with an `Application`, not an `Activity`, `Service`, or other `Context`, so you do not run into garbage collection issues.

Comment: Okay, that sounds great thank you, but in this case how does Google do it in their library ? At no point when I'm using the analytics library for Android do I pass anything other then an app id for analytics. And In their documentation you can read: "Pageviews, events and Ecommerce hits are stored in an _SQLite_ database and
dispatched to the Google Analytics servers periodically"

Comment: You *do* have to pass in a Context. The `startNewSession` method accepts two parameters: your web property id and your activity context: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#samples

Comment: Oh great missed that ! Perfect, I'll get this and forward it to my database singleton class for SQLite dealings. But what do I need to import to use it in my library? Says Context is undefined. +1 upvote and accepted

Comment: @MrBean: `Context` is `android.content.Context`, as is indicated in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).